# ERROR ReferenceError: 'videojs is not defined ' in angular cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, video.js

I am converting my angular 2 project from systemjs to angular cli. I removed all js and css files from index.html and included the all files and videojs css and js files in the angular-cli.json,
project compiled correctly but in the execution i got the error "videojs is not defined",
I am not seeing the error if i include the videojs files in the index.html
can you help me out . how to resolve this error in angular cli?

angular-cli.json file

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "project": {
        "name": "angular-cli-project"
    },
    "apps": [{
        "root": "src",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "assets": [
            "assets",
            "favicon.ico"
        ],
        "index": "index.html",
        "main": "main.ts",
        "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
        "test": "test.ts",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "prefix": "app",
        "styles": [
            "styles.css",
            "./assets/admin/pages/css/lock.css",
            "./assets/css/dashboardPage.css",
            "./assets/css/facebook.css",
            "./assets/css/form.errors.css",
            "./assets/js/videoCapturing/videojs.record.min.css",
            "./assets/js/videojs/video-js.css",

        ],
        "scripts": [
            "./assets/js/videojs/video.min.js",
            "./assets/js/videoCapturing/RecordRTC.js",
            "./assets/js/videojsvideojs.record.js",
            "./assets/js/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls.js",
            "./assets/js/videojs/videojs.hotkeys.min.js",

        ],
        "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
        "environments": {
            "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
            "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
    }],
    "e2e": {
        "protractor": {
            "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "lint": [{
            "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
        },
        {
            "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
        },
        {
            "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
        }
    ],
    "test": {
        "karma": {
            "config": "./karma.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "defaults": {
        "styleExt": "css",
        "component": {}
    }
}
```

Component code :

```
import {Component,OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
declare var videojs :any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-play-video',
  templateUrl: './play-video.component.html',
  styleUrls : [] 
 })
export class PlayVideoComponent implements OnInit{
public videoJSplayer :any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.videoJSplayer = videojs(document.getElementById('example_video_11'), {}, function() {   // here videojs is undefined.
            this.play();
          }
    }
  }
```

play-video.component.html :

```
<video id="example_video_11" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
  controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
</video>
```

[project structure image](https://ibb.co/jOEawQ)

Comment: if you open chrome console and try `videojs` is it undefined?

Comment: yes ,I am seeing the error in console.videojs is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things here

1. your code under `ngOnInit` is missing a closing `)`
2. you should use `AfterViewInit` and not `OnInit` if your accessing the dom directly. (`document.getElementById`)
3. You need to install `@types/videojs` definitions. *Alternatively*, you can use `window["videojs"]()` since videojs will be on the window var.
4. I have just did exactly what you did, added the `video.min.js` to `src/assets/js/video.min.js` then in `.angular-cli.json` added `"./assets/js/videojs/video.min.js"` to `scripts`. It works just fine after doing the above.

Comment: thanks for the answer Ahmed Musallam  ,its working perfectly.

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: I wasted a lot of time, because I added the script under the "test" node instead of the "build" node in my angular 6 application. Be careful about that.